# for line `msi1.put(s, i == null ? i = 1 : i += 1);`, NetBeans complained that it is expecting a variable but instead got a value

Tags: java, list, dictionary, hashmap

I'm trying to store distinct words in a HashMap and count the number of time it appears. Below is the code I have came up with. However, the IDE complained that for line `msi1.put(s, i == null ? i = 1 : i += 1);`, it is expecting a variable but instead got a value. It did not provide any additional information. Could someone please give me hand? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
Map<String, Integer> msi1 = new HashMap<>();

List<String> ls1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("hello", "world", "america", "world"));

for(String s : ls1){
    Integer i = msi1.get(s);
    msi1.put(s, i == null ? i = 1 : i += 1);
}

System.out.println(msi1.size() + "distinct words");
System.out.println(msi1);
```

Comment: Try `msi1.put(s, i == null ?  1 : i + 1);` You don't need to reassign `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a statement in a ternary expression, only an expression. You may want to use this instead:

```
msi1.put(s, i == null ? 1 : i + 1);
```